# passing in props within state expression

Tags: javascript

not sure why this line is coming back undefined.

```
!state.props.category.includes(props.id)
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined is the error I get back but I know for a fact props.category exists. I tried wrapping it with curly braces as well.

```
 const bpmHandler = (props) => {
    !state.bpm.includes(props.id)
      ? setState((prevState) => ({
          ...state,
          bpm: [...prevState.bpm, props.id],
        }))
      : setState((prevState) => ({
          ...state,
          bpm: [
            ...prevState.bpm.filter((query) => {
              return query !== props.id;
            }),
          ],
        }));
  };
```

Comment: Are you writing this in a class component?  Unless you've added the `props` property to your state this won't work. You most likely want `this.props.category.includes(this.props.id)`

Comment: no it's a functional component and I can get the value out of props.category just fine in DOM it's because it's in the expression, I don't know how to wrap it so props.category could just be one value instead of react thinking it's state(1).props(2).category(3)

Comment: In your JSX/dom are you accessing it using `props.category or by using `state.props.cateogry`? Your error is saying that `state.props` doesn't exist (and is `undefined`), meaning your `state` object doesn't have a `props` key defined on it (which results in `undefined.category` which throws the error you're seeing).

Comment: I'm accessing through props.category. There is no state.props you're correct. How do I wrap props.category so that it can just spit out the value of props.category into state.HERE.includes()?

Comment: Please make a executable code as a snippet

Comment: `state.bpm.includes` or `state.props.category.includes`?? can you use console.log(state.props) before that line?

Answer (score 0):

this was a simple fix

```
 !state[props.category].includes(props.id)
```

this fixed it